# VBScript is causing WINWORD.EXE and WSCRIPT.exe to hang up

Tags: vbscript

I have this .vbs script that I use to automate the creation of a .doc file.

This script runs fine when launched from a .bat, or directly from the command line. But I have an external program launching this script and it becomes hung up. When this happens it has a bunch of WINWORD.exe and WSCRIPT.exe entries in the task manager.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code that could cause issues?

```
Const wdReplaceAll  = 2
Const workPath = "d:\work"
Const template = "template\template.doc"
UniqueId = Wscript.Arguments(0)

If Wscript.Arguments.Named.Exists("Tokens") Then
    strTokens = Wscript.Arguments.Named.Item("Tokens")
End If

If Wscript.Arguments.Named.Exists("Values") Then
    strValues = Wscript.Arguments.Named.Item("Values")
End If

arrToken = Split(strTokens,"|")
arrValue = Split(strValues,"|")

if UBound(arrToken) = UBound(arrValue) Then
    CreateFax UniqueId, arrToken, arrValue
else
    Wscript.Echo "Tokens and Values must be same length"
    Wscript.Echo "Tokens: " & UBound(arrToken) + 1 & " Values: " & UBound(arrValue) + 1 
end if

Sub CreateFax(UniqueId, arrToken, arrValue)
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Activate
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = 0
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(workPath & "\" & template)
    for i = 0 to UBound(arrToken)
        FindAndReplace objWord.Selection, arrToken(i), arrValue(i)
    next
    objDoc.SaveAs(workPath & "\" & UniqueId & ".doc")
    objWord.Quit
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplace (objSelection, strFind, strReplace)
    objSelection.Find.Text = strFind
    objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
    objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE
    objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = strReplace
    objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you briefly explain, which external program is calling this script? Do you know wether it is called with cscript or wscript?

Comment: It could be called with either. It is a program that calls iPShellExecute()

Comment: It runs on a server. An automated process starts it, and then the vbs script runs and makes the .doc. But it doesn't run. If I take the command line string it is calling and put it in CMD or a .bat it runs fine...

Comment: Ok, at the question you described an other behavior. If the script runs with the (exactly) same command line, the problem comes from the calling process. (e.g. running in another user context, stucking in a loop...) Heard about this thing called [_`debugging`_](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0):

Even though [StackOverflow isn't a debugging service](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)...

### No, there is not anything *obviously* wrong.

Have a look at the mentioned externel program, the automated process and debug them.

---

I have edited your question and reformatted the code block. For potential answerers it's always more pleasant to find a well described problem, nice formatting and not too much to scroll.